# How to apply a function with conditional logic based on a column's value to each row in a dataset?

Tags: dataset

I'm learning Mathematica Datasets and I need to apply a function to each row in a Dataset the performs some conditional logic.  Here is my Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

I'm want to add a column to this Dataset that is the goal differential in favor of Winnipeg so I can't just subtract column 5 from column 3.  If Winnipeg is the home team it would be column 5 minus column 3.

I assume Mathematica can do this but all I can find is how to apply simple one line functions to each row in a Dataset.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the person downvoting this have anything constructive to add?

Comment: Could you please load this dataset or part of it that you have been experimenting with?

Comment: You may want to look at `Query`.

Comment: Probably the downvoters think the second bullet point of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a sample of the data was not provided

```
ds = Dataset[
  {<|"Visitor" -> "Montreal", "G" -> 5, "Home" -> "Winnipeg", "H" -> 1|>,
   <|"Visitor" -> "Winnipeg", "G" -> 3, "Home" -> "Montreal", "H" -> 4|>}]

ds[All, <|#, "D" -> If[#Home == "Winnipeg", #H - #G, #G - #H]|> &]
```

[image]

Comment: I think we should downvote this answer because it includes a code example and the question didn't.  Seems unfair, and unfairness should be discouraged. ;-P

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the humor! I took a look at Dean Schulze's profile. He has been a member for 7 years and went silent for 7 years after posting his first question. I'm sure the rules and etiquette have changed a lot since then. Perhaps things were more laid back way back then. Dean, please get familiar with the new world order.

Comment: That works.  Thanks.  What did you mean that a sample of the data was not provided?  I showed the data in the screen shot above.  The data was imported from .csv file.  My data isn't a list of associations like you showed.

Comment: @DeanSchulze  `I showed the data in the screen shot above` Mathematica is very powerful software, but it does not yet have a function `ReadDataFromScreenShotAndConvertToPlainTextCode`   May be in V 13 they will add this. This function will be very useful to have.

Comment: Nasser - My data is a Dataset imported from csv, not a list of associations like you showed.  Maybe there is a way to export a Dataset in the form you used?

Comment: A `List` of `Association` is one way to construct a `Dataset`. Evaluate `Normal@dsWIN` and you will see exactly that.